# android studio can't create ActivityRegisterBindingImpl

Tags: java, android

hi when i trying to rebuilding and running my project ,facing with this error:

```
Found data binding errors.

****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. LoginViewModel is missing it file:/home/ramtin/Desktop/QuestionAndAnswer/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_register.xml loc:32:33 - 32:46 ****\ data binding error ****
```

RegisterViewModel class:

```
public class RegisterViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<String> name = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> EmailAddress = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> Password = new MutableLiveData<>();

private MutableLiveData<RegisterUser> currentName;

public MutableLiveData<RegisterUser> getUser() {
    if (currentName == null) {
        currentName = new MutableLiveData<RegisterUser>();
    }
    return currentName;
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    RegisterUser registerUser = new RegisterUser(name.getValue(),EmailAddress.getValue(), Password.getValue());

    currentName.postValue(registerUser);

}

}
```

this is library which i using in my app :

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
```

also see this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol class ActivityRegisterBindingImpl
```

in your idea,where is have problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you configurated databinding as true in gradle file?